# GPU stops sending signal to monitors

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, multiple-monitors

Recently (in the past week) randomly throughout the day both of my monitors will go black with a message that there's no signal being driven to them. The rest of the system is fine: if I'm playing a YouTube video, sound will keep coming through. If I'm running a calculation, the process will finish and close whenever it's done, it's just that I can't actually see anything.

I've tried unplugging the HDMI cables and replugging them in, but that doesn't work. I've tried switching TTY's in hopes of that bringing back the GUI or at least checking logs that way, but doesn't work either. I'm not sure if maybe my Nvidia 970 is dying (unlikely but hey) or some package I installed last week is messing with things.

Is this a known issue? Which logs should I check, and how should I get to them before the start-up process writes all over them to find out what's causing this? System specs are as follow:

Dell U2715 Monitors
Nvidia 970 GTX
nvidia-375.66 drivers

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5120 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.97    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1200x960      59.90  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected primary 2560x1440+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.97    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1200x960      59.90  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a symptom of my video card dying. Replacing the video card solved the problem

Comment: Reviewers - I suggest we close the question as no-repro